# Assigning a Lookup ID based on a matching Name field

Tags: workflow, lookup, salesforce-id

I am trying to take a text field containing a name on one object, and use that name to reference a separate related object to find a match. If a match was found, it will take the ID of the matching record and assign that ID to a lookup field on the original object.

Ex: If Object A has a field called 'Bob Smith', and object B is named 'Bob Smith', a lookup field on Object A will be populated with the ID for object B's record.

Using Process Builder, I've done something similar in the past, but that was when dealing with a limited number of values. This meant I could use IF statements to hard code what the ID would be depending on the match found (IF ObjA.Field.Text = 'Bob Smith' AND ObjB.Field.Name = 'Bob Smith', ObjA.Lookup = '00301Q3A00000jd'), as an example.

But is there way to create this so it dynamic enough to pair names and assign the ID?

Comment: You can theoretically do this in the PB, but it also requires a flow to query the records and update the values based on the results. A trigger would probably be more efficient, though.

Comment: Are you using the actual Salesforce Name field, or a custom field? The Name field is automatically indexed, which is going to make a huge difference in which solutions are feasible past a certain data volume.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

Problems like these are where Apex collections really help out, specifically, a `Map`. The basic idea is that you use some identifier (called the "key", usually a `String` or `Id`) as a pointer to something else (called the "value", which can be essentially anything).

Given the following Map

```java
Map<String, Id> nameToIdMap = new Map<String, Id>();
nameToIdMap.put('Bob Smith', '00301Q3A00000jd');
```

Writing the expression`nameToIdMap.get('Bob Smith')` will return the value `00301Q3A00000jd`, and that expression can be used anywhere that you would normally expect an Id (well, with some caution. If you `.get()` using a key that doesn't exist in the map, you'll get `null` as a result. Try to do much of anything with that `null` value and you'll find yourself the proud owner of a Null Pointer Exception).

As is, the above example is no real improvement over the process builder that you already made. We're still hard-coding the association between names and Ids.

Determining where to go from here means we'll need to stop and think about a couple of things:

- What information will I have?
- What information do I need?

The information you'll have is "data from `ObjectA` records" (assuming you'll be using a trigger to accomplish this), or, at the bare minimum, the `Id` of an `ObjectA` record, and the `Name` of that same `ObjectA` record.

As for the information you need, you've already said that yourself. Phrased slightly differently, you need the `Id` and `Name` of `ObjectB` records (we'll worry about getting specific records in a little bit).

Right now, you only have information from `ObjectA`. If you need other data, you need to query for it.

The general pattern used for querying things looks like this

```java
// Assuming we're in a trigger, and have trigger context variables available...
// First declare a collection (generally a List or a Set) to hold values we will
//   be using in the WHERE clause of the query
Set<Id> acctIdsSet = new Set<Id>();

// Then, iterate over a trigger context variable
for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
    // Gather values
    acctIdsSet.add(opp.AccountId);
}

// Declare a map.
// This map will be used to hold the data we care about
Map<Id, String> accountIdToAccountNameMap = new Map<Id, String>();

// Perform a query for the information we want to retrieve
for(Account acct :[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :acctIdsSet]){
    // Inside this loop, we populate the map we previously declared with the data
    //   that we're interested in
    // We're not hard-coding this data here as we were in the previous example
    // We're using information we have to query information we want, and then 
    //   recording the result in a "generic" or "abstract" manner (i.e. there
    //   are a limited number of lines of code that we write, and it works on
    //   _any_ record without modification)
    accountIdToAccountNameMap.put(acct.Id, acct.Name);
}

// Finally, iterate one more time over the records we initially had.
// If this is in a "before" trigger, and you're updating records in trigger.new or
//   trigger.newMap, then no additional DML is required.
// Otherwise, you'll need to create a List to hold the records you want to update
//   and perform DML on that list after the loop finishes.
for(Opportunity opp :trigger.new){
    // now that we've set up a mapping between information we have (account id)
    //   and information we want (account name), we can update our initial records
    opp.Account_Name_Custom_Field__c = accountIdToAccountNameMap.get(opp.AccountId);
}
```

That was a bit of a trivial example. The object and field names that you'll use will be different, but the code you end up with should look pretty similar (that's why it's called a "pattern").

- Instead of `Opportunity`, you'll be working with some `ObjectA`.
- Instead of gathering Ids, you'll be gathering Names of your `ObjectA` records
- The map will be a `Map<String, Id>` (instead of the other way around)
- The query for `ObjectB` will use `Name` instead of `Id` in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Thank you for talking this one through - very thorough. Obviously I have some work ahead of me, but it could be a good learning process. Will update once I've tested it out.

Comment: @AnonWonderer One thing I forgot to mention. One big advantage to the "gather, query, loop" pattern I described is that it only queries records that you _will_ end up using (as opposed to querying every `ObjectB` record). This helps keep you within the 50,000 query row governor limit. It can also help with query selectivity (i.e. how much work Salesforce needs to do to run your query). It's not foolproof, but a rule of thumb is the smaller `[records queried] / [total records for object]` is, the more "selective" the query is (and Salesforce will complain if your query isn't selective enough).